# Laplace transformation of 1/(s-1)^4

Tags: laplace-transform

"Hi, I have a question about Laplace transformation.The question is:"
$y
′′(t) − 2 y
′
(t) + y(t) = t e^
t
, y(0) = y
′
(0) = 0$

"I know"

$Y(s)(s^2-2s+1)=1/(s-1)^2$

$Y(s)=1/(s-1)^4$

"and I know we can use Partial fraction decomposition, but I don't Know in this case when we have power 4.
The answer is "

$Y(s)=(1/3!)(3!/(s-1)^4$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Recall the [First Shifting Theorem](http://mathfaculty.fullerton.edu/mathews/c2003/LaplaceShiftingMod.html) for Laplace transform which states:

$$\mathcal{L}\{e^{at}f(t)\}(s) = \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}(s-a).$$

In your case you have the last part of the equation 
$$\dfrac{1}{(s-1)^4} = \dfrac{1}{3!}\mathcal{L}\{t^3\}(s-1).$$

*Proof of the theorem:*

$$\mathcal{L}\{e^{at}f(t)\}(s) = \int^\infty_0e^{-st}e^{at}f(t)\,dt = \int^\infty_0 e^{-(s-a)t}f(t)\, dt = \mathcal{L}\{f(t)\}(s-a).$$

The inverse of $\mathcal L$ in the transform follows:

$$\mathcal{L}^{-1}\{{F(s-a)}\}(t) = e^{at}f(t).$$

In your case

$$Y(s) = \dfrac{1}{(s-1)^4} \Rightarrow y(t)= \frac{e^tt^3}{3!}.$$

Answer (score 1):

If you had $Y(s) = 1/s^4$, then you know what to do, yes?

Remember also the exponential shift formula, $L[ e^{ct} y(t)] = Y(s-c)$ where $L[y] = Y$.

---

Added:

$$L^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s^4}\right] = L^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{3!}\frac{3!}{s^4}\right] = \frac{1}{3!} L^{-1}\left[\frac{3!}{s^4}\right] = \frac{1}{6} t^3$$

Now, by the Exponential Shift Formula,

$$L^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{(s-1)^4}\right] = e^t L^{-1}\left[\frac{1}{s^4}\right] = \frac{1}{6} e^t t^3$$

Comment: sorry I'm not following.

Comment: If you had to find the inverse Laplace transform $L^{-1}$ of $Z(s) = 1/s^4$ what would it be?

Given that, what is $L^{-1}$ of $Y(s) = Z(s-1)$. Use the exponential shift formula.

Comment: Hint: $L[t^n] = n!/s^{n+1}$ for $n = 1, 2, 3, ...$

Comment: $Did you mean e^-4t$

Comment: See what I just added. Make sense?